# Zooming in onto an Excel linear graph

Tags: microsoft-excel

Consider the data as follows

```
alg1        alg2       alg3

57,55       56,25      59,9

92,1        93,5       92,2

104,7       103,7      103,85

108,9       109,65     108,75
```

I would like to make a linear graph in Excel to show the differences between three algorithms. However, the differences are small (e.g. 57,55 and 56,25) compared to the overall values. As a result, the lines merge and one cannot see the small differences. Is there a way in Excel (or maybe a different program) to make a linear graph where I can zoom in onto this small range such as 55 to 60 or 90 to 95 and somehow skip/zoom out the 60-90 range?

Comment: Are you opposed to making two different graphs? If so, you can have a secondary y axis in the same graph although you might need to make two data sets.

Comment: @cerebrou: Can you post a picture of how you have the graph set up?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard In my opinion it seems the best idea, but unfortunately the OP has three series of data.

Comment: On a personal commentary, if your precision is to the hundredth of a second and you are having differences of seconds, there wouldn't be that big a difference to make it noteworthy. Although, it depends entirely on the real problem being solved by the algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Well, supposing you aren't opposed to something like the following:

[image: End result]

Select the data and make a "Line Graph" (I apologize for terminology mistakes, but this is a Portuguese version of Excel 2003, and surprisingly a lot of things don't map well with English). Make it Line oriented. You should have something like this.

[image: Selecting Data Series Formatting]

Right-click on the series you want to format (it can either be the series with the lower values or the highest, on this I selected the three highest) and press on something on the lines of Format Data Series.

[image: Axis Tab]

In there, direct yourself to the Axis tab and select Secondary Axis, then press OK. The secondary axis will be the one on the right, and you can configure it to your heart's desire.

It might be confusing to know which data series belong to each axis so two suggestions is to alert the readers of this or make the series and corresponding axis of different color.

Answer (score 1):

In my example I put two charts, each one having one data series.

[image]

To ensure they have the same size I copied one from the another. They share the same X values (column `A`) and the lower one uses `B` values for Y, and the upper - `C`.

Because they need to have the same scale on the Y axis, I manually set that they both have range of 30 (30-60 and 100-130). But you may make height of the lower chart eg. 2 times smaller and then set the range to be 15 (eg. from 40 to 55).

I deleted the X axis from the upper chart.

For demonstration purposes I left borders of each chart, but you can easily delete them by setting no border in chart properties. I also forgot to change data names, so they both have "Serie1" label.

If you'd wish the charts to have common chart legend, you may delete the box from upper chart and add invisible series (ie. out of plot range) with the same colour on the lower chart.

Answer (score -2):

Someone please correct me if wrong, but I think for Excel you'll have to seperate each point into two cells, for x and y.

Create two columns to the right of each alg point. The first will pull the x coord with the formula (assuming A1 is where the point is at):

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(",",A1))
```

The second column will pull the y coord with:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(",",A1))
```

The result would be like:

```
alg1        
57,55 57 55
```

You'll then be able to start making charts with these two columns, for each algorithm.

To zoom in, you can also edit the axis scale in code. For example:

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 60
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 80
```

Comment: Only if you wanted to make a dispersion plot. Besides, this doesn't answer the problem - how to avoid having too far-away values displayed on a graph.

Comment: I believe he already has the chart made. He just wants to know how to zoom into a smaller region of the chart.

Comment: Aaron, I think that in "55,57" the comma is a decimal point.

Comment: @Voitcus, good point. With that being the case, perhaps just creating a macro (with code to change the axis scales as above) would work?

Comment: If I understand correctly, he wants something [like this](https://wiki.ecdc.europa.eu/resized-image.ashx/__size/550x0/__key/CommunityServer-Wikis-Components-Files/00-00-00-00-02/0285.image003.gif) (however with the empty part on Y axis not X)

Comment: I did also think that way, but Excel doesn't allow it, AFAIK. Besides, and until the OP says a proper use to the data, the functionality he desires can be easily made with matplotlib or Gnuplot (by "easily" I mean to those who know how to use non-intuitive tools)